# How to set other player's armor in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-behavior-packs

I'm making an MCBE behavior pack which adds kits via functions (functions are to be executed by command blocks). I want to make it so that the player doesn't have to equip armor; instead, it automatically slots the armor into the required places. I don't know any sort of command for that, and I can't find anything through Google.

Answer (score -1):

If your still interested the command /item replace would be the way to do it on java
on bedrock I believe there's a /replace item command that would work similarly
[image]

I have 4 command blocks to do this
bottom command block: Impulse Unconditional Needs redstone

```
item replace entity @a armor.head with minecraft:leather_helmet
```

second command block: chain conditional always active

```
item replace entity @a armor.chest with minecraft:leather_chestplate
```

third command block: same as seccond

```
item replace entity @a armor.legs with minecraft:leather_leggings
```

fourth command block: same as second

```
item replace entity @a armor.head with minecraft:leather_boots
```